# golang static stop index.html redirection

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

func main() {
  fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))
  http.Handle("/", fs)

  log.Println("Listening...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

So I have a index.html file and want server to stop showing it.

Comment: It seems you are new here. These questions are more useful if you are very specific about what you were trying to do. When you say, "I want server to stop showing it." I wonder, if you don't want to show it, why not just delete the index.html file. ("Having a file" can be interpreted different ways.) Maybe there is a language barrier here, I just made the assumption that you didn't want the auto-generated index.html, which is the problem I had too.

Answer (score 2):

The docs for [FileServer](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) state that:

> As a special case, the returned file server redirects any request
>   ending in "/index.html" to the same path, without the final
>   "index.html".

So `/index.html` is redirected to `/`, `/foo/bar/index.html` is redirected to `/foo/bar/`.

To avoid this register an additional handler for the special case.

```
http.HandleFunc("/index.html", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, err := os.Open("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
        return
    }
    http.ServeContent(w, r, "index.html", time.Now(), f)
})
```

Please note I'm using [ServeContent](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeContent) insead of [ServeFile](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) because `ServeFile` handles `/index.html` requests the same way as `FileServer`.

Comment: No I type / and I want the directories to show instead of index.html

Comment: `I have a index.html file and want server to stop redirecting to it.` is different from `I want the directories to show instead of index.html` so please rephrase your question.

Comment: Regarding the redirect, I found another solution to that problem. While handling the `/` you can check `request.URL.Path` (or similar environment variable) to verify if the URL should be rejected or not. In any case, I agree the question is vague and confusing. For a language that is so strict about type checking, it's surprisingly loosey-goosey with URL redirects.

Answer (score 1):

There's no redirection going on, the default file to render when requesting a directory is `index.html`. The directory listing is a fallback for when this file isn't found, so you can't get a directory listing without removing the `index.html` file.

If you want a directory listing, you'll have to write it out yourself, which you can then format and style however you choose. The basic structure is very simple if you want to write it directly, take the internal `dirList` function for example:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
fmt.Fprintf(w, "<pre>\n")
for _, d := range dirs {
    name := d.Name()
    if d.IsDir() {
        name += "/"
    }
    url := url.URL{Path: name}
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>\n", url.String(), htmlReplacer.Replace(name))
}
fmt.Fprintf(w, "</pre>\n")
```

Comment: Helpful answer. Regarding the "fallback" behavior, it seems dangerous to expose all the files in there by default, but that's just my opinion :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 3 ways:

1. Make a PR which allow accessing `/index.html` without redirect to golang's **net/http/fs** library. https://github.com/golang/go/issues/53870
2. Hack your code: replace `/index.html` with `/` to stop 301 redirect, e.g., https://github.com/ahuigo/go-lib/commit/1a99191d5c01cf9025136ce8ddb9668f123de05c#diff-67e8621fbb99281a50c089bae53d4874663d3d21ca5e90809ec207c070029351R44
3. Customize your own http fs handler  instead of official tools.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an "images" directory for your images, like this:

```
http.Handle("/images/", http.StripPrefix("/images/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("images"))))
```

But you don't want to expose all the filenames in there. As people say, "Silence is golden."

In a browser, by default, going to `/images` or `/images/` or `/images/index.html` shows a listing of all the files there, which is not really something you want to do accidentally.

I think the easiest solution from the command-line:

```
touch index.html
```

This creates an empty file that blocks the auto-generated images/index.html directory listing. And this doesn't block access to any of the images in there. Of course, a hacker could still try to brute-force guess what files are in there, so you need to use some common sense.